# Why does .focusout when .submit is called - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to provide form feedback to users as they unfocus off inputs and when they submit the form. It works when I have just the focusout method but fails when i add the submit method.

```
(function(){
        $('input').focusout(function(){
            if($(this).val() == ""){
                $('.jsError').html('<p class="alert alert-danger text-center">'+$(this).attr('name')+' is required.</p>'); 
            }
        });

        //when the submit button is pressed
        $("#register").click(function(event){
            //var input = $(this).parent().find('input[value=""]');
            if(!input.length){
                event.preventDefault();
                $('.jsError').html('<p class="alert alert-danger text-center">'+Please fill in the form+'</p>');
            }else{
                //set variables
                var email = $('#email'),
                    emailConf = $('#emailConf'),
                    pass = $('#pass'),
                    passConf = $('#passConf'),
                    stageName = $('#stageName'),
                    mainClub = $('$mainClub'),
                    mainSkill = $('#ent_main_skill'),
                    termsAgree = $('#agreeToTerms');
            }
        }); 
})();
```

I was thinking it was the event.preventdefault but that itself doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Your logic should be the opposite no? If `input.length` is truthy it means that there are some errors since you query elements without a value.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see by looking at the commented line, you are trying to query all inputs that wont have a value. That means if `input.length` is greater than `0`, there are errors but if it's `0` it means all the form fields have been filled.

The logic you implemented does the opposite, it should be:

```
if (input.length) {
    //errors
} else {
   //no errors
}
```

Comment: That would explain why prevent default is not working maybe, but not why the unfocus stops working when I add the submit method

Comment: @user2251229 Well, do you have any JS errors in the console when you add your click listener? Make you that you uncommented the line of code that defines `input`. If it's not working, please setup a jsfiddle example.

Comment: @user2251229 Well a real-time collaboration is not quite useful, unless we are both there ;) Can you just setup a normal jsfiddle?

Comment: sounds good, so I'm just at work right now so will be able to post in about a two hours. Thanks for all the feedback by the way